# Which story is real in The Life of Pi?

Tags: plot-explanation, life-of-pi

After watching *Life of Pi* for the 16th time, I realized I had plenty of questions: the tiger in the movie could be a metaphor for God or Pi himself (according to the two stories provided), also the zebra could be a metaphor for the Buddhist, the orangutan for his mother, and the hyena for the cook.

He could have lied about the story in the ending, since the Japanese wanted a realistic story, but it could also have been the truth, as he couldn't face the real story.

I really don't know which story to believe. Is there any conclusion which one is real?

Comment: Deciding which version you want to believe is sort of the point.